# Mac OS X losing keyboard shortcuts and spaces

Tags: macos

One of my collegues in the company uses a Mac (10.5.8) and recently he loses his keyboard shortcuts (ALT+TAB, ...) and his Spaces after a while.
The only way to resolve this is a restart.

It occurs very randomly so I can't give a lot of information about this.
Does anyone recognize this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to troubleshoot this, but in the case of any random glitches, your best bet would be to try in a **new user account** and see if the problem persists there.

If that's the case, I'd just migrate to a new user profile.